# Using Protractor to select a uib-dropdown option

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

The DOM I'm testing against a uib-dropdown (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown ), but having trouble selecting a specific option from the dropdown.

Taking this rendered HTML snippet, for example, I want to select the `Assets` dropdown option:

```html
<tr>
<td>
<div id="drpAccount">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown open" uib-dropdown="">
 <button id="single-button" style="color:white;" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
     Account : <b class="ng-binding">Assets</b> <span class="caret"></span>
     
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu accounts-dropdown" uib-dropdown-menu="" aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
     <li ng-repeat="accountChoice in ctrl.accountOptions" class="ng-scope">
  <a ng-click="ctrl.selectOption(accountChoice)" style="font-family:Arial;" class="ng-binding">Assets</a>
     </li><li ng-repeat="accountChoice in ctrl.accountOptions" class="ng-scope">
  <a ng-click="ctrl.selectOption(accountChoice)" style="font-family:Arial;" class="ng-binding">Equity</a>
     </li><li ng-repeat="accountChoice in ctrl.accountOptions" class="ng-scope">
  <a ng-click="ctrl.selectOption(accountChoice)" style="font-family:Arial;" class="ng-binding">Liabilities</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

and this original project markup :

```html
<td>
<div id="drpOrg" style="height:18px;z-index:9999;">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown style="left:2px;top:2px;">
 <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" uib-dropdown-toggle>
     Organization : <b>{{ctrl.selectedRoot.DESCRIPTION}}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu org-dropdown" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
     <li ng-repeat="rootChoice in ctrl.rootOptions">
  <a ng-click="ctrl.moreFuncs(rootChoice)">{{rootChoice.DESCRIPTION}}</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

I have this javascript code, using `Protractor` e2e testing framework:

```js
 this.selectBalSheetDropdown = function (searchObj, drpIndex) {

        var elem = element(by.id('drpAccount'));
        var elementSwitcher = elem.element(by.css("div[uib-dropdown]"));        
        elementSwitcher.element(by.css("button[uib-dropdown-toggle]")).click();  // OPENS DROPDOWN FINE !
        
        // ***** HOW TO GET DROPDOWN VALUE FOR "Assets" option, as an example ??
        //elementSwitcher.element(by.css("a[value=Assets]")).click();
    };
```

Any advice on selecting specific dropdown option is appreciated.

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this solution using `by.linkText()`, but I'm open to other ways :

```
 this.selectBalSheetDropdown = function (searchObj, drpIndex) {

  var elem = element(by.id('drpAccount'));
  var elementSwitcher = elem.element(by.css("div[uib-dropdown]"));        
  elementSwitcher.element(by.css("button[uib-dropdown-toggle]")).click();

  // *** using by.linkText() works as well ***
  elementSwitcher.element(by.linkText('Liabilities and Equity')).click();

};
```

Comment: I'd say this is one of the best approaches - quite simple and readable!